# Running Parallel Tests using Gauge Framework with Browserstack

Tags: java, browserstack, parallel-testing, getgauge

I'm using Gauge framework and Browserstack for my test scenarios. I'm researching how can i parallel execute my test scenarios(.spec) using browserstack?

I read many documentation but I couldnt see anything about Gauge framework to run parallel test. 
I tried to use Junit or NG  but i couldnt adapt them.Is it impossible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Luckily, [Gauge has support for running specs in parallel](http://getgauge.io/documentation/user/current/advanced_readings/execution_types/parallel_execution.html) by setting a flag and specifying the max number of threads allowed:

```
gauge --parallel -n=4 specs
```

Assuming your spec files are in /specs/. Depending on your build tool, there are various plugins that can facilitate the same. For example, [here is a repo for Maven + Gauge + BrowserStack](https://github.com/brendanorourke/gauge-browserstack).

It will run four specs-- in parallel-- for Chrome, Firefox, and IE. The important piece there is the gauge-maven-plugin and the  flag in the POM.xml.

Feel free to clone it down and run on your BrowserStack Automate account!