# How to set up Gauge Automation tests to work with multiple browsers

Tags: getgauge

I am starting a UI automation project in the Thoughworks Gauge platform.  The example I have has internet explorer set as the default.  I'm trying to set up multiple environments with different browsers.

I can't seem to see in the Gauge documentation how to set this up.

Can anyone help,

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of the below:

- Use `env` to spinoff multiple browsers. See [example](https://github.com/getgauge-examples/cross-browser).
- Use a crossbrowser testing platform underneath. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41273363/326543) for details